# Scaling by dragging 1 corner of a 4 vertex plane stretches the texture

Tags: transforms

[image]

I drag the top right corner of a rectangular plane for a scale operation. However the image did not scale proportionally. How can I scale so that the entire image is scale proportionally?

Comment: quads are made of 2 tris, so if you don't have enough topology, it will twist the image texture as explained by Mehdi

Answer (score 4):

This type of distortion happens whenever there is not enough geometry for Blender to interpolate between the vertices.

#### Solution

To solve the problem, add more geometry by either subdividing the plane in edit more, or by adding a subdivision surface in *simple mode*.

#### Demo

In the example below, a level of 3 subdivisions was necessary in order to get rid of the stretching.

Before activating the subdivision surface modifier:

[image]

After activating the subdivision surface modifier:

[image]

Comment: OMG!!!  Thumbs up!!! Thanks a lot for the answer. It even worked for the video playing in the plane.